# What productions does parser use in this to parse given string?

Tags: compiler-construction

For dangling if-else statement. Grammar given is

**stmt -> matched_stmt | unmatched_stmt**

**matched_stmt -> if expre then matched_stmt else matched_stmt | other**

**unmatched_stm -> if expre then stmt | if expre then matched_stmt else unmatched_stmt**

How to parse this this python if else statement

```
x=int(input("Enter the value of x "))
if x<=10:
    print("in 10")
    if x<=5:
        print("in 5")
else:
    print("greater than 10")
```

Comment: If whitespace is significant in Python your grammar is wrong, and if it isn't your indentation is incorrect, which is possibly the only source of your confusion.

Comment: Indentation is correct. I think grammar is incorrect. But grammar is from ullman aho sethi compiler design book.

Comment: The Dragon book was written decades before Python was invented. If the indentation correctly expresses your intent, i.e. that the `else` associates with the first `if`, your grammar does not describe it.

Answer (score 1):

Python's syntax does not exhibit the dangling else ambiguity, because the body of the if statement and the existence of the optional else clause are are precisely delimited by indentation. Another way to avoid the problem is to insist that `if` statements be terminated by a keyword, such as `fi`.

In any case, the Dragon book grammar does not apply to Python.